# [TRAC]: Generate (welcome) pages for individual and specific user name?

Tags: plugins, trac

I want TRAC to generate individual pages for specific user name.

For example USER1 after successful login will see:

- USER1_logo.jpg
- USER1_welcome_text
- USER1_link_to_http_ftp_file

The same way USER2 will see his/her individual page/pages. Especially I'm interested in putting links exclusive to user name in welcome page or sub pages.

Does anyone know a plugin or a way to do this?

Comment: [SOLVED]: Install those TRAC plugins: TracMyPagePlugin and TracUserPagePlugin. Read documentation for them on http://trac-hacks.org/

Comment: @killdaclick- To make it easier for people that come across this question in the future, please enter your comment above as an answer and mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]: Install those TRAC plugins: TracMyPagePlugin and TracUserPagePlugin. Read documentation for them on trac-hacks.org